# Client-service interaction logic

Tags: wcf, service, architecture, soa

There seem to be several ways to implement client-service interaction logic.

**Variant 1**

Client implements an object model similar to object model on a service (e.g. `WCF Data Services`). Client makes changes to objects, creates and registers new objects. When done, state of created and changed objects is sent to service. Service restores existing objects from the database / creates empty objects and merges state.

**Variant 1b**

The same as V1 but instead of sending state client sends changes in objects' state to service.

**Variant 2**

Client doesn't send object state to service at all! Instead it invokes service methods, service changes objects and notifies client about changes. Client applies these changes as is.

**Questions**

1. What variant is preferable?
2. How is the second variant called exactly and where can I find more information about it?
3. What framework can be used to make changes in objects' state on service *automatically* apply on client?

Comment: I would say the preferred variant would depend on the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FirstLaw.html

That's the very first rule you should follow, and quite contrary to what Tim said, it doesn't really depend on what you're trying to solve, that's exactly the reason we can find very nasty pieces of software every they. You're not trying to solve a domain problem, which would be very specific, you're rather trying to implement an architecture and for that there are right and wrong ways of doing things.

It seems that you already know that you want to use webservices, so let me recommend you to build a REST API using ASP.NET rather then WCF as it is easier to work with.

As for your variations, I would go with the second as it is the one the fits the REST principle. Your "server" holds the objects and you ask it, by using the REST API to change their states. Also, a client should never hold a copy of a server object, a client should instead, hold a model that represents what that object looks like on the server. This is quite contrary to what used to happen with technologies like .NET Remoting, Corba, RMI... in which the client used server objects through object proxies and called methods directly on them, very much like your variation 1, but we are now past that, and more and more APIs are built around stateless APIs with REST.

- 1 - 2
- 2 - It really depends on what you want kind of technology you want to use. If you're on the MSFT side of things ASP.NET Web API is a grand stack, and for the client (UI), maybe ReactJS
- 3 - The only way you can achieve this with the stack I told you about would be by using websockets which invoke client client callbacks. You can use SignalR which implements the same functionality with client pushes using ajax calls.